# Not able to access object member variables

Tags: python, oop, constructor

I am new to python and am facing a strange error.
The basic idea of my demo is to perform "*Constructor Overloading*" in python, similar to other programming languages.
I have two files, one file that holds only the class, and another file to create objects of the class.

**employee.py**

```
class Employee:
  def displayEmployee(self):
    print("Name : ", self.emp_name,  ", Salary: ", self.salary)

  def __init__(self,id=None,salary=None,emp_name=None):
      print("Constructing MyClass")
      if(id is None):
        self.id=101
      else:
        self.id = id
      if(salary is None):
        self.salary=20000
      else:
        self.salary = salary
      if(emp_name is None):
        self.emp_name="Default"
      else:
        self.emp_name = emp_name
```

**runner.py**

```
from employee import Employee

emp1 = Employee()
emp2 = Employee(1,3000,"Abcd")

emp1.displayEmployee();
emp2.displayEmployee();
```

However, now I am facing an error as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "runner.py", line 7, in <module>
  emp2.displayEmployee();
File "D:\python\Demo\employee.py", line 3, in displayEmployee
  print("Name : ", self.emp_name,  ", Salary: ", self.salary)
AttributeError: 'Employee' object has no attribute 'emp_name'
```

That means I am not able to access any of the member variables of the class in a function of the same class. This is quite puzzling to me with respect to other programming languages.
Am I doing something wrong or is this by design?

**UPDATE:**

Based on the recommendation I have updated the python files to the following. However, I am still facing the same error, which is also given below.

***employee.py***

```
class Employee:
  def displayEmployee(self):
    print("Name : ", self.emp_name,  ", Salary: ", self.salary)

def __init__(self, id=101, salary=20000, emp_name="Default"):
    print("Constructing MyClass")
    self.id = id
    self.salary = salary
    self.emp_name = emp_name
```

***runner.py***

```
from employee import Employee

emp1 = Employee()
emp1.displayEmployee();
```

*Error:*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runner.py", line 6, in <module>
    emp1.displayEmployee();
  File "D:\python\Demo\employee.py", line 3, in displayEmployee
    print("Name : ", self.emp_name,  ", Salary: ", self.salary)
AttributeError: 'Employee' object has no attribute 'emp_name'
```

Comment: You forgot else statements on your if None comparisons. For example, how did you expect the ID to be anything other than None, or 101? Also, python doesn't need semicolons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass arguments that are not `None` they are never assigned as attributes of `self`. You could modify your `__init__` to simply provide default values then assign them as attributes to your class

```
def __init__(self, id=101, salary=20000, emp_name="Default"):
    print("Constructing MyClass")
    self.id = id
    self.salary = salary
    self.emp_name = emp_name
```

Comment: I have followed your suggestions, yet i am still getting the same error. Please check my update to the question.

Comment: @Samwell Tarly In updated `employee.py`, Fix the indent on `def __init__` properly the same as `def displayEmployee`, after that, It works for me.

Comment: @SangminKim , Correct! It seems I have a lot to do with getting used to python's indentation style.